# python generators duplicates

Tags: python

How do I either avoid adding duplicate entries into a generator or remove them once there are already there?

If I should be using something else, please advice.

Comment: Show some code... we don't even know what your generator is supposed to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the values are hashable, the simplest, dumbest way to remove duplicates is to use a `set`:

```
values = mygenerator()
unique_values = set(values)
```

But watch out: sets don't remember what order the values were originally in. So this scrambles the sequence.

The function below might be better than `set` for your purpose. It filters out duplicates without getting any of the other values out of order:

```
def nub(it):
    seen = set()
    for x in it:
        if x not in seen:
            yield x
            seen.add(x)
```

Call `nub` with one argument, any iterable of hashable values. It returns an iterator that produces all the same items, but with the duplicates removed.

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can collapse adjacent duplicates if you're willing to do a bit of work.

```
print [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby([1, 2, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Input should be sorted though, but still very nice!